Next.js: Prevent Static CSS File Name Changes Between Builds to Maintain Cache Integrity
Description:
I am facing an issue with Next.js where static CSS file names change between builds, causing caching problems for search engines like Google. Here is a detailed description of the problem and what I have tried so far:
Problem Description:
Next.js generates static JS and CSS files during the build process. When styles are changed and a new build is created, Next.js regenerates these static files with new names. For example, after the initial build, the network tab might show:
Home Page: 1.css, 1a.css
About Page: 2.css
Contact Page: 3.css
After changing a style on the home page and rebuilding, the file names could change to:
Home Page: 123.css, 1a.css
About Page: 2.css
Contact Page: 3.css
The Issue:
Google caches the old file names (1.css for the home page, for example). When the page is crawled again, the updated CSS file (123.css) is not found, leading to broken styles in cached versions.
What I've Tried:
To solve this issue, I attempted to modify next.config.js to ensure static CSS files retain the same names across different builds. However, this approach has led to numerous errors, indicating it might not be the correct method.
Request for Help:
I need an optimal solution to prevent static CSS file names from changing across builds in Next.js. The goal is to maintain cache integrity with search engines. Any insights or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.
Tech Stack

Nextjs 13
TailwindCSS
there is global css and also css imports for libraries like react-toastify and swiper

Here is the image of the problems for more clarity
The file name of current build notice link page and network
enter image description here
after adding "cache:" before the link notice the broken styles in google cache version and network tabenter image description here
What I've Tried:
To solve this issue, I attempted to modify next.config.js to ensure static CSS files retain the same names across different builds. However, this approach has led to numerous errors, indicating it might not be the correct method.

Do you have any updates on this? I'm actually facing the same issues
